# TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

i`m learning Rest-API with python in ubuntu . i want to use SQLAlchemy to store my data to SQLite data base . 
this are my codes

**BookModel.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json
from settings import app

db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__='books'
```

what should i do ?

```
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float,nullable=False)
    isbn =db.Column(db.Integer)

    def add_book(_name,_price,_isbn):
        new_book=Book(name=_name,price=_price,isbn=_isbn)
        db.Session.add(new_book)
        db.Session.commit()


    def get_all_books(self):
        return Book.query.all()


    def __repr__(self):
        book_object = {'name':self.name,
                       'price':self.price,
                       'isbn':self.isbn}
        return json.dump(book_object)
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

i use from bellow commands in python to create database and it works .

```
>>> from BookModel import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

next i use below commands to test add_book() method .

```
>>> from BookModel import *
>>> Book.add_book("ss",55.6,556)
```

but PyCharm show me below error .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/momo/Projects/flask_rest_aPI /BookModel.py", line 18, in add_book
    db.Session.add(new_book)
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'
```

Answer (score 1):

`db.session` must be lowercased.

try

```
db.session.add(new_book)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `BookModel`:

the function `add_book` you have:

```
    db.Session.add(new_book)
    db.Session.commit()
```

which should be:

```
    db.session.add(new_book)
    db.session.commit()
```

and by the way the `add_book` and `get_all_books` functions should be `classmethod`:

```
    @classmethod
    def add_book(cls, _name, _price, _isbn):
        new_book=cls(name=_name,price=_price,isbn=_isbn)
        db.session.add(new_book)
        db.session.commit()


    @classmethod
    def get_all_books(cls):
        return cls.query.all()
```